# How to use "case when" when you want variable to be assigned to multiple values?

Tags: sql

I use a data management system that works using SQL. It allows users to select values and then queries are run to fetch data based on the user inputs. For my problem, a user has the option to input a specific location (city) or multiple locations for the equipment they are looking up in a certain state and when they don't enter anything, the location_id defaults to 0. I am trying to code the logic so that if the location id is 0, the it will query all location_id's in that state. and if the user does input a specific or multiple location it will just use those location_id's.

```
select * from equipment e 
where e.equipment_type = 4
and e.start_date <= '2022-01-31'
and (e.end_date is null or e.end_date > '2022-01-01')
and e.state = 'TX'
and e.location_id = case when {location_id} = 0 then e.location_id else {location_id} end
```

this is the code I have now and the {location_id} is the syntax in my system to use the input the user selected. this will work when the user only inputs one location id but will not work when there are multiple. I have tried doing

```
 e.location_id in case when {location_id} = 0 then e.location_id else ({location_id}) end
```

in hopes that it when location_id is 0 it will instead do e.location_id in (input1, input2,...) but it does not work. Any suggestions on how to fix this will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Just `and ( {location_id} = 0 or e.location_id = {location_id} )`

Comment: As Stu says, skip the case expression, use regular AND/OR instead.

Answer (score -1):

User input of '0' fetches data for all locations in the state.
The query correctly filters tblequipment data based on the specified location IDs, handling single or multiple IDs separated by commas.

```
    -- Create the 'tblequipment' table
    DROP TABLE If exists tblequipment;

    CREATE TABLE tblequipment (
        tblequipment_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
        tblequipment_type INT,
        start_date DATE,
        end_date DATE,
        state VARCHAR(2),
        location_id INT
    );

    -- Insert sample data into the 'tblequipment' table
    INSERT INTO tblequipment (tblequipment_id, tblequipment_type, start_date, end_date, state, location_id)
    VALUES
        (1, 4, '2022-01-15', NULL, 'TX', 1),
        (2, 4, '2022-01-20', '2022-02-15', 'TX', 2),
        (3, 4, '2022-01-25', NULL, 'TX', 3),
        (4, 4, '2022-01-30', '2022-02-28', 'TX', 4),
        (5, 4, '2022-02-01', NULL, 'TX', 5);

    -- Display the data in the 'tblequipment' table
    -- SELECT * FROM tblequipment;

    DECLARE @location_id varchar(100);

    -- Set the location_id based on user input (0 for all, or a multiple location)
    SET @location_id = '0'; -- 0 lists all
    SET @location_id = '1, 3'; -- lists 1, 3

    SELECT * FROM tblequipment e
    WHERE e.tblequipment_type = 4
      AND e.start_date <= '2022-01-31'
      AND (e.end_date IS NULL OR e.end_date > '2022-01-01')
      AND e.state = 'TX'
      AND (
        (@location_id = '0') OR
        (e.location_id IN (SELECT CAST(value AS INT) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@location_id, ',')))
      );
```

Comment: This is not ISO standard SQL, how did you determin the OP's specific DBMS product?

Comment: Good question, I presumed it to be a Standard SQL as there is no information from the requester on the DB management system used

by the looks of the requester query seems to be SQL Server?!

Comment: But STRING_SPLIT etc are product specific.

Comment: I can offer precise code if the user specifies the platform they are using. For generic questions that don't mention a specific database, I can only provide code tailored to a particular relational database management system (RDBMS). @jarlh

Comment: @Stu
if you can ascertain the specific database system the user is using, I can then provide code customized for that particular system.

Comment: So which dbms is the above code for? You have given a product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified.

Comment: @SenthilPNathan you would need that information from the OP, my crystal ball is currently unplugged.

Comment: @jarlh - SQL Server!!!!!!!!

Recopyug the comment "I can offer precise code if the user specifies the platform they are using. For generic questions that don't mention a specific database, I can only provide code tailored to a particular relational database management system (RDBMS). "

Comment: @Stu
Absolutely, my crystal ball is currently unplugged as well! We'll need to ask the OP for more details on their database system to provide the right code.

Comment: I concur, so your answer should be deleted until if/when this info is provided.

Comment: The next time you give a product specific answer to a question for an unknown dbms, at least tell OP (and the rest of us) which dbms it's written for.

Comment: @jarlh Absolutely, I'll make sure to do that in the future!